# how to maintain space between edittext and keyboard in viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am using view pager and i have edit text in my third fragment but when i focused on edit text the soft keyboard hides the edit text but if i types multiple lines and deletes them then keyboard does not hides the edit text.

I am using edit text inside Relative layout but keyboard overlaps the relative layout and hides the edit text.

I want that keyboard should not hide the relative layout

or

If we can place some space between edit text and Keyboard

I've tried Bottom Margin, android:windowSoftInputMode found many of the solution for individual activity but they did not work in full screen view pager

Comment: use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Used but did not worked

Comment: I am using Full screen with viewpager